# Is there a way to add all of the recipients of an email to a group/folder in contacts from Mail?

Tags: mail.app, contacts

In mail, I'll get email to a list of about 50 people, all of whom need to be in my address book. Is there a way to add them all at once? I can tell it to add one at a time, but I can't seem to get it to do more than that.

Comment: I've encountered several other people in real life asking this question in the last week. I can't find a built-in way to do this. People I've talked to seem amazed this requires an AppleScript, but it's the only thing I've come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps an AppleScript like this one can help. Note that I'm not really proficient in AppleScript, so I'm sure this can be improved, but no one has answered so far.

```
  tell application "Mail"
    set theSelection to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
    set theSubject to subject of theMessage
    set groupName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter name for new contacts group" default answer theSubject buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue")
    tell application "Address Book"
        set theGroup to make new group with properties {name:groupName}
    end tell
    set theRecipients to to recipients of item 1 of theMessage
    repeat with a from 1 to count theRecipients
        set theRecipient to item a of theRecipients
        tell application "Address Book"
            set theName to name of theRecipient
            tell application "Mail" to set theAddress to address of theRecipient
            set thePerson to make new person with properties {first name:name of theRecipient}
            make new email at end of emails of thePerson with properties {value:theAddress}
            add thePerson to theGroup
        end tell
    end repeat
    set theRecipients to cc recipients of item 1 of theMessage
    repeat with a from 1 to count theRecipients
        set theRecipient to item a of theRecipients
        tell application "Address Book"
            set theName to name of theRecipient
            tell application "Mail" to set theAddress to address of theRecipient
            set thePerson to make new person with properties {first name:name of theRecipient}
            make new email at end of emails of thePerson with properties {value:theAddress}
            add thePerson to theGroup
        end tell
    end repeat
    tell application "Address Book" to save
  end tell
```