# How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, file, symlink

What command is used to create a symbolic link/soft link?

Answer (score 704):

```
┌── ln(1) link, ln -- make links
│   ┌── Create a symbolic link.
│   │                         ┌── the optional path to the intended symlink
│   │                         │   if omitted, symlink is in . named as destination
│   │                         │   can use . or ~ or other relative paths
│   │                   ┌─────┴────────┐
ln -s /path/to/original /path/to/symlink
      └───────┬───────┘
              └── the path to the original file/folder
                  can use . or ~ or other relative paths
```

```
$ echo content > original
$ ln -s original symlink
$ ls -la original symlink
-rw-r--r--  1 grgarside  staff    8 28 Jan 18:44 original
lrwxr-xr-x  1 grgarside  staff    8 28 Jan 18:44 symlink -> original
$ cat symlink
content
```

For more information about ln(1) see the [man page](http://cl.ly/T9bq).

The path to the symlink is optional; if omitted, `ln` defaults to making a link with the same name as the destination, in the current directory:

```
$ cd ~/Documents
$ ln -s ../Pictures
$ ls -l Pictures
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  11 Feb  1 17:05 Pictures -> ../Pictures
```

To create a symlink to replace a system directory (e.g. if you want to have `/Users` pointing to another disk drive), you need to [disable System Integrity Protection](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/). You can re-enable it after the symlink is set up.

Comment: If only man pages were as clear as your answer!

Comment: If only man page writers had thought to use the term "original"!  Just like everything in life, the original always comes first.

Answer (score 105):

The command is called `ln`. If used with the option `-s` it will create a symbolic link in the current directory:

```
ln -s /any/file/on/the/disk linked-file
```

If you want to overwrite an already existing target (`linked-file`), use

```
ln -Fs /any/file/on/the/disk linked-file
```

Answer (score 42):

I know this question is explicitly asking about the Terminal, but if you're in GUI Land and don't want to enter Terminal Land, you can use [SymbolicLinker](https://github.com/nickzman/symboliclinker/releases). This puts a "Make Symbolic Link" option in your Services menu in Finder.

[image: A context menu for a folder, showing a "Services" submenu, with "Make Symbolic Link" hilighted]
[image: A context menu for a symbolic link, with "Make Symbolic Link" hilighted]

Comment: I'd love to know why this was downvoted so I can make higher-quality answers from now on :)

Comment: probably because the question was "How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal?" But I am not downvoting you :)

Comment: @EdwardFalk I think in El Capitan, you can hold `Command`+`Option` while dragging a file... will update the answer later

Comment: @BenLeggiero That makes an alias.

Comment: @BenLeggerio, The difference is explained here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/whats-the-difference-between-alias-and-link

Answer (score 40):

It's just `ln -s <source> <destination>`.

Answer (score 10):

`ln -s /some/dir/ ~/Desktop/dir`

You can also create a symlink for directory using the same command

`ln -s "$(pwd)" ~/Desktop/dir`

To create symlink to current directory you are in.

Comment: A simple `.` (dot) will give the pwd. No fancy arguments needed :)

Comment: @mylogon hahaha i like to overthink sometimes. simplified my answer!

Comment: @mylogon i just realised that `.` doesnt work on macOS. didnt try on linux yet. using `./` resulted in this `foo -> ./foo` which points to itself.

Comment: What is the full command you typed out?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the source path is relative to your destination, use an absolute path to your source path, and put it in single quotes

```
$ ln -s '/any file/could have (special chars)/or spaces/test' '/some/other place/file'
```

You can always figure out the current full unescaped path to something by going to that folder in the terminal, then typing

```
$ pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

As a heads up to anyone, you **must use full path names**. This wasn't immediately clear to me, as I felt I could symlink relative paths in a folder that I was running the command inside. I could be wrong (I'm a macOS novice).

For example, if I try to symlink my Pictures folder inside of my Downloads folder, **while cd'd in my user home directory**, this will not work:

```
Users\stevebauman >_ ln -s Pictures Downloads
```

Instead, you must use:

```
Users\stevebauman >_ ln -s /Users/stevebauman/Pictures /Users/stevebauman/Downloads
```

Comment: Not exactly - the link has to be expanded from where it is so ln -s ../Pictures Pictures works. The link works as if you cd to where you store the link