# Sync custom App Shortcuts via iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, shortcut

I know that with Mavericks and iOS 7, iCloud syncs text shortcuts automatically across devices. Does iCloud also sync custom Application specific Shortcuts across Macs?

Application specific shortcuts:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, App Shortcuts are not synced over iCloud.**

The shortcuts are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`, so if you want to sync them you are free to symlink this through Mobile Documents, however that file contains many preferences outside of just your app shortcuts.

Comment: Are symlink is the links I get via the context-menu at the "Make Alias" option?

Comment: @Lukas No, see [How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal)

Comment: Thank you! But wouln't it cause some problems when syncing system preferences like display settings and so? Would it "sync" all settings are just some?

Comment: @Lukas Indeed, all the settings stored in .GlobalPreferences would be synced which is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Are all settings in the .GlobalPreferences? The Startup Disk for example is saved in the PRAM, which settings would be synced, which wouldn't?

Comment: @Lukas There isn't a canonical list of settings that are in .GlobalPreferences or are in their own property list. A majority of OS X settings are in there but not many app settings. Feel free to have a look through though. Note that syncing the .GlobalPreferences is very bad if you have two Macs attempting to write to the file at the same time — iCloud doesn't handle synchronous modifications well at all.