# How do I remove a single key combination from the Mac Keyboard shortcut menu?

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut, macos

I know I can set shortcuts by clicking on none and entering my chord. But I can't figure out how to set it back to none without clicking "Restore Defaults" which destroys my entire config, also it means I can't remove any default shortcuts.

Right now if I really want to remove something I just give it some ridiculous key combo I'll never press, or just disable it but this seems dumb, especially for things that I still want to show up in context menus, but not have shortcuts.

Comment: I set a bunch of shortcuts to try and figure this out and now I can't unset them! Argh!

Comment: lol apologies for your sacrifice, it is appreciated. I'm pretty sure I can go into like some .plist config file and edit the file directly, but that can't be the only way. I hate doing that since I end up breaking stuff half the time

Comment: I looked at plists based on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87647/128627, but couldn't find anything. Maybe I just missed it though. You could also have a poke around with https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296321