# Is it possible to let Picasa use a removable device as the Application Support folder using symbolic links?

Tags: symlink

Picasa stores very large files in Application Support folder which consumes limited disk space in system disk. I wonder if I can use symbolic links in order to make Picasa use removable disk as storage space.

Comment: I would think your App will crash once the removable disk is not connected. Is it a big issue?

Comment: Not a big problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I have no experience with Picasa, I have symlinked many other apps' Application Support folders to other destinations including network drives too without any problems. I ensure the drive is connected with a script before allowing the app to open, but I'm not sure if that's necessary. Generally speaking, it'll work fine.

```
┌── ln(1) link, ln -- make links
│   ┌── Create a symbolic link.
│   │                                      ┌── the path to the new folder
│   │                                    ┌─┴────────────────┐
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/App /Volumes/MyDrive/App
      └────────────┬───────────────────┘
                   └── the path to the original file/folder
                       can use . or ~ or other relative paths
```

<sup>Edited from my canonical linking answer at [How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give an example on how to define such a symbolic link?

Comment: @Mert Edited :)