# Applications and preferences on USB drive

Tags: macos, usb

Is it possible to have applications, plugins and preferences installed on portable media such as USB drive?

I have two identical computers, one at work and one at home, and I'd like to have the exact same setup on both. Example on applications I use:

Firefox (with extensions)
Sublime Text
Linux programs in Terminal
uTorrent
Alfred

Answer (score 2):

Applications (i.e. .app bundles) can be stored anywhere, including external media. Preferences is more complicated, although the simple solution is probably to [symlink](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115647/) the preference files and container to the external media.