# Why OSX symlink cannot Relative PATHs?

Tags: macos, path, symlink

System in OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan

```
$ cd $HOME
$ ls .
> Dropbox
> BTsync
```

Code which creates unsuccessful symlink

```
ln -s BTsync/ Dropbox/
```

Code which creates working symlink

```
ln -s /Users/masi/BTSync/ /Users/masi/Dropbox/
```

### Evidence in size difference with files

```
$ cd $HOME
$ ln -s $HOME/BTsync/wfdb.zip $HOME/Dropbox/
$ ln -s BTsync/wfdb.zip Dropbox/wasi.zip
$ ls -la $HOME/Dropbox/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 masi  staff    41 May 17 22:45 wfdb.zip -> BTsync/wfdb.zip
lrwxr-xr-x   1 masi  staff    46 May 17 22:45 wasi.zip -> /Users/masi/Dropbox/wfdb.zip
```

### Evidence with directories

```
$ ln -s /Users/masi/BTsync/cam\ local/ /Users/masi/Dropbox/
$ ln -s BTsync/cam\ local/ Dropbox/camLocal2
$ ls -la $HOME/Dropbox
lrwxr-xr-x   1 masi  staff    37 May 17 22:52 camlocal -> /Users/masi/BTsync/cam local/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 masi  staff    25 May 17 22:53 camLocal2 -> BTsync/cam local/
```

and visually same in Finder

[image]

which shows that the two commands are not the same in El Capitan.
Using absolute PATH only works.

### Evidence with Relative PATH

```
$ cd $HOME
$ ln -s ./BitTorrentSync/cam\ local/ ./Dropbox/camlocal3
$ ls -la Dropbox/ 
lrwxr-xr-x   1 masi  staff    27 May 17 22:58 camlocal3 -> ./BTsync/cam local/
```

and a new screenshot

[image]

---

Why OSX Symlink cannot Relative PATHs?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't about relative paths. [Relative paths work fine.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal/115647#115647)

If what you're trying to do here is create a symlink from Dropbox to BTsync, the problem is that Dropbox already exists. This means the symlink is created *inside* the Dropbox folder, named BTSync. Delete Dropbox and try again.

If you really meant to create a symlink inside the Dropbox folder, then both these commands work identically.

Comment: @Masi You want BTsync to be a symlink **to** Dropbox? Then you've got your arguments the wrong way round. Check the link in my answer for the basics of symlinking.

Comment: @Masi Please edit your question back to avoid confusion. I tried both commands in 10.11.4 and they work identically. Are you getting an error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Please, see the body for the proofs.