# ln symbolic link command error - iphone bu symbolic link troubleshoot

Tags: iphone, terminal, error, symlink

Having problem changing iphone backup location (following this tutorial https://www.iclarified.com/72786/how-to-change-your-iphone-backup-location-mac)

cannot interpret the error - any help appreciated !

```
sudo ln -s/Volumes/bbyfrn/Backup ~/Library/Application\ 
Support/MobileSync/Backup
ln: illegal option -- /
usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [link_name]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... linkname_dir
       link source_file link_name
```

Comment: Be careful how you copy things when you cut and paste and then edit the command you removed a space after -s  . I will make a usual comment here only use sudo if you know what the command does - that includes understanding its error messages as sudo can mess up your machine.

Answer (score 2):

You’re missing a space after `-s` before the path beginning with `/`.

You can tell this from the error message ‘invalid option’ of `/` as it’s read the punctuation character as another short option next to s rather than as part of the next argument.

[How can I create a symbolic link in Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/115646/37797)

Also don’t use sudo — you own the folder in your home directory.

Comment: Also, it looks above like the `Support/MobileSync/Backup` part is on a separate line, but in order to work right it must be on the same line as the `ln ... ~/Library/Application\ ` part *and* there must be exactly one space after the ```\``` and before the `Support/...` part.